# What is the difference between function createFolds and createDataPartition in caret

Tags: caret

I think the two functions are all to split the data, but I really can't get the difference between both of them, even I has read the help manual of them.

Answer (score 5):

The help page for those functions says:

> "`createFolds` splits the data into `k` groups"

and

> "A series of test/training partitions are created using `createDataPartition`"

So, `createDataPartition` does one or more splits of the data (into two groups). You saw that in your other post that it can be used to create a single split.

`createFolds` will split the data into `K` groups of roughly equal size (presumably to use with K fold CV)

Comment: Thank you. I think I can understand more about it now, I'll try more.